# Why is there a vertical scrollbar on my svg at 100%?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, fullscreen, internet-explorer-9

Can somebody explain why I see a vertical scrollbar in Chrome and IE9 with the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fullscreen SVG</title>

    <style>
      html,body {
        margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;    
      }

      .fullscreen {
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg class="fullscreen"></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I replace the svg with a div it works perfectly. But if I put the svg inside that div, the layout is broken again:

```
<div class="fullscreen">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Changing the doctype to XHTML seems to fix the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But inline SVG is a part of HTML5 so...

In the meantime I also filed a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70487).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm a little late here, but I stumbled across this when I was trying to solve a different problem.

I don't think what you're experiencing is a bug. The SVG tag is an inline element by default (for the record, IMG tags are too) and DIVs are considered block elements. I'm thrown off a little here because you aren't supposed to be able to set height/width to inline objects (If you tried to do this on a SPAN, the height/width is ignored).

You might consider this another workaround, but explicitly setting the display property to block removes the scrollbar. Floating the SVG element would also fix this.

```
.fullscreen { display: block }
```

It appears that the HTML5 DOCTYPE is based off of the W3C's strict DOCTYPES (not the transitional). Both strict declarations also display the scroll bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

So at this point, it might be best to refer to a different discussion if you care about strict vs transitional DOCTYPES: [Browser Rendering Difference Between strict/transitional DOCTYPEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735979/browser-rendering-difference-between-strict-transitional-doctypes)

Hopefully this adds a little value to value to the discussion.

Comment: It's strange that I can set width and height to an inline element. and it gets bigger than when it is declared as block. Thanks for the hint. Inspecting the computed svg css in Chrome dev. tools indeed shows that it is inline by default.

Answer (score 15):

To build on Corey's answer, `inline` or `inline-block` elements are called "inline" because they are intended to be laid out amongst lines of text. So, wherever they appear, space is reserved for the "descent", which is the area underneath a line of text where the [dangly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) parts of lowercase g's, j's, and y's go.

So that's where the extra space comes from when your `svg` element has `display: inline`. You can manipulate the amount of space reserved with the `line-height` property, or you can remove it altogether by setting `display: block`, as Corey noted.

I believe you're able to set the height and width on `img` and `svg` elements because they are, in CSS parlance, "replaced" elements, and behave a little differently than regular inline elements. [The CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) explains how this works in more detail. And as far as specs go, it's actually pretty readable.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution would be to just add the CSS rule `overflow:hidden` to the html and/or the body tag.

```
html, body { overflow:hidden; }
```

**Edit**

Another solution would involve using the XHTML doctype. This works in Chrome, and I suspect it works in IE9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: That's not a solution, that's a workaround. I don't want workarounds, I can come up with those myself. I'm looking for whether there is a reason for this behavior or it is a bug. I will give you +1 because this might be good for someone with the same problem and looking for a practical answer.

Comment: Its a fine line between a solution and a workaround. If you put in a a proper doctype in your example it displays without the scrollbars
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
Or at least it does in Chrome, I don't have IE9 installed.

Comment: `<!Doctype html>` is a proper doctype, I want to use HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try resetting the margin and padding on the svg tag, like you've done with html and body. Could be some default styles on the svg.

Comment: nope, already tried that, found some more strange behaviors: svg inside the div causes problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CSS question to me, have you checked [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSS+100%25+height+on+div) already?