# Why there is a vertical scroll on this html5 page?

Tags: html, css, svg

Why there is a vertical scroll on this html5 page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head><body>
  <svg></svg>
</body></html>
```

Comment: When I change the Value of  svg {
      width: 98%;
      height: 98%;
    }
like this No Scroll

Comment: Svg is an inline element

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758638/why-is-there-a-vertical-scrollbar-on-my-svg-at-100

Comment: @AkshayJoy That's not the right way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svg` is an inline element just like `img` or `span`, not sure this is a bug or what but using `display: block;` does fix the issue

```
svg {
   display: block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AZ7ts/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide `display:block` it should disappear. It is weird for the inline element to behave this way but not sure why this is happening...

```
 svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display:block
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nV6Ck/show)